# How to make a inner div 100% height with sticky footer?

Tags: html, css

I have this page (http://www.alsite.com.br/angelogarcia/angelogarcia.html) that has a Sticky Footer (http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

So I need the div `#main` is 100% height minus the size of the footer(70px), and my div `.conteudo` is the same size of the div `#main`, 100% height too. I've set colours to be easy to see what happens

I'm clear?

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/EugRP/

The structure is:

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="sidebar"></div>
        <div class="conteudo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

my CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}


#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}
#main {
    width:100%;
    min-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
        background: #FFCC00;
    padding-bottom: 70px; /* must be same height as the footer */
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -70px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 70px;
    clear:both;
}

.conteudo{
    padding:0 15px;
    width:60%;
    margin-left: 30px;
    background: #000000;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}
```

Comment: if you could create a reduced test case on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) it'd be easier to assist you with your code.

Comment: here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/EugRP/

Comment: Depending on your browser support needs, this sounds like a job for calc.  http://caniuse.com/#search=calc Something like: `calc(100% - 70px)` might work for your needs

Comment: Edit: Something similar to this: http://jsbin.com/OQurEFU/2/edit?html,css,output Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yeah, something like that... ty for idea!..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a 'spacer' div

CSS

```
#spacer {
    height: 100px; // same height as footer
}
.main {
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="sidebar"></div>
        <div class="conteudo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You could give `main` a css declaration of `margin-bottom: 70px;`

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the .conteudo = (#main + #footer) = 100% ??

Suggestion :
Set your #main = 95% , #footer = 5%

Solution ：
Check the pixel-height of the client browser using javascript
(Everyone's monitor may not be the same)
and then just calculate the pixel

But if you don't know how javascript work, learn it yourself, Google is useful.

English isn't my mother language, hope I explained well.

Comment: javascript? it's only css dude, and i can't use %, i need the #footer with fixed height.

Comment: You can change the CSSstyle using javascript=,=

Answer (score 0):

Ok... Just Copy and Paste these line below = =

<---Start of javascript--->

var htmlHeight;

htmlHeight = document.getElementById("Page").style.height;

document.getElementById("main").style.height = htmlHeight - 70;

<---End of javascript--->

Paste these line between  and

Remember , add a id to your >html< (id="Page")
Also , add a id to your >div name="main"< (id="main")
The "element" that control the height of #main is the height of html.
Then, #main = (height of html) - 70px

If it didn't work, try to place the javascript to the bottom(inside html)
If this also fail, learn javascript

Although html is the Body of your web, don't forget javascript is the heart of web

Comment: i know that... ty for help!